# how to control pen tablet pressure input with a joystick?

Tags: graphics-tablet, gamepad, joystick

)

i have a pen tablet Genius G-pen F610 and its working perfectly in Ubuntu 12.04

but for drawing purpuses i need to block pen pressure input (which is easy to do mechanicly just by removing the plastic tip of the pen)

and then somehow to control the presure by gamepad or joystick, for example the more I move the joystick to the left the more pressure is detected (by drawing software) to be coming from the pen

the result should be that I am still drawing lines with the pen but the thickness of the line is controlled by joystick

thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any easy way to accomplish that, Gimp has some functionality to read from other input devices, but I don't think you can freely mix and match inputs from different devices (see `Edit->Input Devices` and `Preferences->Input Devices`). Not sure about Krite, MyPaint and all the other graphics apps.

Linux however has the uinput interface that lets you create virtual input devices and with that you can read input events from your tablet and your gamepad and mix them together into a virtual input device. However that requires some programming. You can find some example source code that might get you started at:

- https://github.com/Grumbel/udraw